# Is the $n$th triangular number greater than or equal to the $n$th prime?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p_n$ be the $n$th prime. For which values of $p_n$ would the following inequality be satisfied?
$$\frac {n^2+n}{2}\ge p_n$$
I have no programming skills, so checking this one number at a time is rather difficult. So far I have verified it for every number less than $100$. I would guess that a way to prove it would be Bertrand's Postulate or the PNT, but I am not sure. Is this a corollary of another theorem or just an obvious statement or is it plain wrong?

Comment: The PNT is the right tool; it implies that $p_n$ is in $O(n\log(n))$, meaning $\frac{n^2+n}2$ is greater than $p_n$ for all large enough $n$. Presumably one could use more explicit bounds to prove this for all $n$ (but I lack the expertise to point to any strong enough result, though I'm sure it's out there)

Comment: The inequality fails for $n=1$ and holds for $2\le n\le 10^8$ and probably for all larger integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Approximations_for_the_nth_prime_number), $p_n<n(\log n+\log\log n)$ for $n>6$. So all you have to do is prove $\log n+\log\log n\le(n+1)/2$ for $n$ sufficiently large, and that's a standard intro Calculus type problem.